Find the eigenvalues of linearly dependent $A$ without using characteristic polynomial. And compute $A^{2024}$
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}25 & 11 & -16 \\ 50 & 22 & -32 \\ 75 & 33 & -48 \end{bmatrix}
$$
a) Find the eigenvalues of $A$ without calculating $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$
b) Find the $2024$th Power of $A$
My attempt:
a) since $A$ has linearly dependent columns, $A$ is non-invertible, which implies $\det(A) = 0$, which implies there exists at least one eigenvalue equal to $0$. By trial and error, I found that one of the eigenvalues is $-1$ with an eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ and by using the fact that the trace of $A$ is $-1$, the third eigenvalue is $0$.
so, $\lambda(A) = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ not sure if this is correct or if there is better method.
b) Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it's possible to compute this because $A$ is non-diagonalizable since it has linearly dependent columns.

$A$ has linearly dependent columns DOES NOT imply $A$ is non-diagonalizable!

@Zhanxiong okay, 不好意思兄弟. i meant to say because the eigenvalues of A is not independent (there are two 0's), they are undiagonalizable

@RioPurnama That's not true in general: Any multiple of the identity matrix is diagonal but has repeated eigenvalues.

@RioPurnama This implication is even more unwarranted. You can easily find numerous counterexamples -- the most trivial one may be $A = 0$.

As you correctly found, we have $$
A\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
25x+11y-16z \\
50x+22y-32z \\
75x+33y-48z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
Z\\
2Z\\
3Z
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $Z = 25x+11y-16z$. In other words, $A$ is a matrix which has rank one as a linear transformation : every vector is mapped onto a multiple of the same vector $[1,2,3]^T$.
Therefore, the rank of $A$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$ is equal to $1$, since its range is spanned by the vector $[1,2,3]$. By the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel of $A$ has dimension $3-1 = 2$, which is to say that the eigenvalue $0$ of $A$ has multiplicity $2$. The last remaining eigenvalue is easily calculated from noting that trace$(A) = -1$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, which is why the eigenvalues are $0,0$ and $-1$ with multiplicity.
This is slightly different from your argument, in that I deduced the nullity as two directly, instead of deducing that it's at least one using the determinant, and then finding the last eigenvalue to also be $0$ using the trace. But both are fine methods.

Once this is true, you have to make more of your structure, though. Because the range of $A$ is the subspace spanned by $[1,2,3]$, the range of $A^2,A^3$ and so on are also this space. The diagonalizability argument doesn't hold water.
Instead, you have to ask yourself a very simple question. If you're given a vector $v$, then $Av$ will be a multiple of $[1,2,3]$. If I know how $A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$ looks like, then I know immediately, for example, how $A^2v$ would be, since $A^2v = A(Av)$ where $Av = c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$ for some $c$. This would also hold for higher powers of $A$.
However, we already know that $A$ has an eigenvalue of $-1$. Since the range of $A$ is spanned by just $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$, this gives us just one possibility (up to scaling) of the eigenvector corresponding to $-1$, which is $\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$. Therefore, it follows that $$
Av = -v \text{ for all } v = c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix},c \in \mathbb R.
$$
Now if $v \in \mathbb R^3$ is arbitrary then $Av = c\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{bmatrix}$ for some $c \in \mathbb R$, so $$
A^{2024}v = A^{2023}(Av) = (-1)^{2023}(Av) = -Av \implies A^{2024} = -A.
$$
This would be the answer to the question.

Rigorously speaking, "nullity is two" does not imply the (algebraic) multiplicity of $0$ is $2$ automatically -- it just implies that the multiplicity of $0$ is at least $2$.

(a) As you've apparently observed, all of the columns of $A$ are multiples of one another, and so we can write it as a (nonzero) outer product, $A = {\bf v} {\bf w}^\top$. In particular, $\operatorname{rank} A = 1$, hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with geometric multiplicity $2$.

 If the $3$rd eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$, then $\lambda = 0 + 0 + \lambda = \operatorname{tr} A = -1$.

(b) Since $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0, 0, -1$, $A^2$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $0, 0, 1$.

 Thus $A^2$ is idempotent and $A^{2024} = (A^2)^{1012} = A^2$. But $A$ satisfies its own minimal polynomial, $m_A(t) = t^2 + t$, i.e., $A^2 + A = 0$.


Denote vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 25 \\ 11 \\ -16 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ by $u$ and $v$ respectively, it is then easy to re-write $A$ as
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 25v & 11v & -16v\end{bmatrix} = vu^\top. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Thus $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 1$, whence its nullity is $2$, which implies that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and its (both the geometric and the algebraic) multiplicity is $2$. To determine the remaining one non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda$, we can then proceed as in @Travis Willse's answer.
The representation $\eqref{1}$ of $A$ is also convenient for solving the second question.  By the associative law of matrix multiplication and the fact $u^\top v = 25 + 22 - 48 = -1$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
A^{2024} &= vu^\top vu^\top \cdots vu^\top vu^\top \\
&= v(u^\top v)\cdots(u^\top v)u^\top \\
&= v(-1)\cdots(-1)u^\top = v(-1)^{2023}u^\top = -vu^\top = -A.
\end{align*}

very elegant solution

Compute the reduced row echelon form of $A$, which should be very quick since all the rows are scalar multiples of the first row. The you will be able to find a basis for the nullspace. This will give you two linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 0$. Using the other eigenvector you've already found, you'll be able to diagonalize $A$ and compute any power of it.
